# Extracting number of specific length from a string in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, regex-recursion

I am trying to extract a set of numbers from comments like

```
"on april-17 transactions numbers are 12345 / 56789"
"on april-18 transactions numbers are 56789"
"on may-19 no transactions"
```

Which are stored in a column called "com" in table comments

My requirement is to get the numbers of specific length. In this case length of 5, so 12345 and 56789 from the above string separately, It is possible to to have 0 five digit number or more more than 2 five digit number.

I tried using regexp_replace with the following result, I am trying the find a efficient regex or other method to achieve it

```
select regexp_replace(com, '[^0-9]',' ', 'g') from comments;

                      regexp_replace                   
----------------------------------------------------
          17                          12345   56789
```

I expect the result to get only

```
column1 | column2
12345     56789
```

Comment: Are there always 2 and only 2 numbers which would be the matching case?  Or, could there be just 1 or 3 five digit numbers?

Comment: Yes it possible to have more, 0 five digit number or more than 2 five digit number

Comment: The problem is that you cannot create a dynamic numbers of columns in an easy way. You need to know how many columns you would get.

Comment: So if we limit it to two, how can we achieve it?

Comment: Gave an solution for exact two columns. It is not possible to get one column at one try and two at the second. If we limit it two, always two columns are shown even if you find only one number. The second one would be NULL in this case. This is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to create query which gets an arbitrary number of columns: It cannot create one column for one number and at the next try the query would give two.

---

For fixed two columns:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2e6f96d0ad3b3407cd169056779e5d05)

```
SELECT 
   matches[1] AS col1,
   matches[2] AS col2
FROM ( 
    SELECT
        array_agg(regexp_matches[1]) AS matches
    FROM
        regexp_matches(
            'on april-17 transactions numbers are 12345 / 56789', 
            '\d{5}',
            'g'
        )
) s
```

1. `regexp_matches()` gives out all finds in one row per find
2. `array_agg()` puts all elements into one array
3. The array elements can be give out as separate columns.

Comment: if those input comments are coming from table column the above SQL statement is not resulting with all the values

Comment: @Maverick You should adjust your query of course. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=65549ab18ba01b35fcce056f924c2b49 ... This one holds the elements without any number: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=eaf43d8ce4c40fd287b86ca8f9170ec1